# How to change size of the pixmap image in PyQt4?

Tags: python, image, pyqt, qpixmap

```
first_row = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

setings_search = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
search_label = QtGui.QLabel()
search_pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
search_pixmap.load('search.png')

#search_pixmap.scaledToWidth(130)
#search_pixmap.scaledToHeight(130)

search_label.setPixmap(search_pixmap)

setings_search.addWidget(search_label)
first_row.addLayout(setings_search)
```

The image doesn't resize when I use both `scaled` and `scaledToWidth/Heigth` methods. 
[my window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETkJH.png)

On the picture I've shown what I already have and what I want to have.

Of course I can change size via Photoshop but I wonder how to do it programatically.

Comment: `search_pixmap = search_pixmap.scaledToWidth(130)`, etc.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: You should give a complete, minimal example showing the error.

Answer (score 9):

As ekhumoro says in a comment, just use one of the `scaled` methods in QPixmap.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

label = QtGui.QLabel()

pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
pixmap.load('test.png')
pixmap = pixmap.scaledToWidth(20)
label.setPixmap(pixmap)

label.show()

app.exec_()
```

gives exactly the right size.

[image]

Comment: not working....

Comment: @NishantBhakta Thanks for the comment, there was a small typo in the last line. Not sure if you meant that though.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `paintEvent` for your `QWidget`. However, I only know how to paint the `pixmap` on an absolute position (`posX`, `poxY`), not sure about relative position (i.e., in a `QVBoxLayout`).

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    qp = QtGui.QPainter()
    search_pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('search.png')
    qp.drawPixmap(posX, posY, width, height, pixmap.scaled(width, height, transformMode=QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation))
```

where `width` and `height` are dimensions of your scaled `pixmap`.